# Change arrays from php version 5.2.5 to php 8.0.26 (for datatable)

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I've got a datatable working with php version 5.2.5, I installed new wampserver version with php 8.0.26, My datatable doesn't work with new wampserver php 8.0.26, show the following error:

**DataTables warning: table id=order_data - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1**

This is my code for datatable, there I call php code to populate datatable (fetchAcumulado.php):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
   var dataTable = $('#order_data').DataTable({
       "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast":"Último",
                    "sNext":"Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                 },
                 "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
            },
                                    //Seleccion de item por pagina
            lengthMenu: [[20, 50, 100, 200, -1], [20, 50, 100, 200, 'Todos']],
columnDefs: [
            { width: 485, targets: 1 }
        ],
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"librerias/php/fetchAcumulado.php",
     type:"POST"
    },
    drawCallback:function(settings)
    {
     $('#totalBs').html(settings.json.totalBs);
     $('#totalUSD').html(settings.json.totalUSD);
    }
   });

    
  
 });
```

This is fetchAcumulado.php code where, I think I have to change arrays format to php 8.0.26, but I don't know how to make it:

```
<?php



include "conexiondbpdo.php";

$column = array('id_secuencia', 'nombre', 'monto', 'mesano');

$query = '
SELECT * FROM gastosacumulados,cuentas,tasa
WHERE gastosacumulados.id_cuenta=cuentas.id_cuenta AND (gastosacumulados.id_cuenta LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR cuentas.nombre LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR mesano LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR monto LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%") 

';

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY id_secuencia ASC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $connect->prepare($query . $query1);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

$data = array();

$total_order = 0;

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = $row["id_secuencia"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["nombre"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["mesano"];
 $sub_array[] = number_format($row["cambio"]*$row["monto"], 2, ",", ".");
 $sub_array[] = number_format($row["monto"], 2, ",", ".");

  $totalUSD = $totalUSD+($row["monto"]);
 $totalBs = $totalBs + $row["cambio"]*floatval($row["monto"]);
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function count_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM gastosacumulados";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
 'draw'    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 'recordsTotal'  => count_all_data($connect),
 'recordsFiltered' => $number_filter_row,
 'data'    => $data,
  'totalBs'    => number_format( ($totalBs), 2, ",", "."),
  'totalUSD'    => number_format( ($totalUSD), 2, ",", ".")
);

echo json_encode($output);


?>
```

These are libraries that I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.3.6/js/tests/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is my datatable working on php 5.2.5:
[image]

Datatable error on php 8.0.26:

[image]

Please any ideas?

Comment: Use your browser's network tab to inspect the response from `fetchAcumulado.php`. There's likely a PHP notice or warning at the top of that response that's making the result not true JSON. For your debugging purposes, all of your JS code is likely irrelevant in determining the issue other than showing us that an ajax request is made. But that doesn't behave any different if you're hitting an endpoint in PHP 5.6, PHP 8.2, Python, Node, etc. The response data from the endpoint is what matters.

Comment: To verify that the array format itself doesn't need to change, you could add `var_dump($data); die;` to your PHP file and confirm that the array structure is the same between your PHP 5 and 8 endpoint.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#response is what I mean about the browser's developer tools to view the response.

Comment: You database code is wide open to SQL injection and I would not expect to produce working results continuously. This is independent to the PHP version, albeit not continuing using PHP 5.2 in 2023 is perhaps sane. Provide the actual error picture as @WOUNDEDStevenJones already commented, I'm with him, you need to share/read the acutal error otherwise you're looking into the wrong places and only guessing.

Comment: _"Please any ideas?"_ - the error message itself already referred you to a page that contains further debugging instructions - did you just ignore that?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all, I fixed the problem, I was very easy, I've got to declare varieables before use them:

```
$totalUSD = 0;
 $totalBs = 0;
```

This is fetchAcumulado.php code:

```
 <?php
    
    //fetch.php
    
    include "conexiondbpdo.php";
    
    $column = array('id_secuencia', 'nombre', 'monto', 'mesano');
    
    
    $query = '
    SELECT * FROM gastosacumulados,cuentas, tasa
    WHERE gastosacumulados.id_cuenta=cuentas.id_cuenta AND (gastosacumulados.id_secuencia LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
    OR gastosacumulados.id_secuencia LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
    OR gastosacumulados.monto LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
    OR cuentas.nombre LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%") 
    ';
    
    if(isset($_POST["order"]))
    {
     $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
    }
    else
    {
     $query .= 'ORDER BY id_secuencia ASC ';
    }
    
    $query1 = '';
    
    if($_POST["length"] != -1)
    {
     $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
    }
    
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    
    $statement->execute();
    
    $number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();
    
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query . $query1);
    
    $statement->execute();
    
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    
    $data = array();
    
    $totalUSD = 0;
     $totalBs = 0;
    
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
     $sub_array = array();
     $sub_array[] = $row["id_secuencia"];
     $sub_array[] = $row["nombre"];
     $sub_array[] = $row["mesano"];
     $sub_array[] = number_format($row["cambio"]*$row["monto"], 2, ",", ".");
     $sub_array[] = number_format($row["monto"], 2, ",", ".");
    
      $totalUSD = $totalUSD+($row["monto"]);
     $totalBs = $totalBs + $row["cambio"]*floatval($row["monto"]);
     $data[] = $sub_array;
    }
    
    function count_all_data($connect)
    {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM gastosacumulados";
     $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute();
     return $statement->rowCount();
    }
    
    $output = array(
     'draw'    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
     'recordsTotal'  => count_all_data($connect),
     'recordsFiltered' => $number_filter_row,
     'data'    => $data,
      'totalBs'    => number_format( ($totalBs), 2, ",", "."),
      'totalUSD'    => number_format( ($totalUSD), 2, ",", ".")
    );
    
    
    echo json_encode($output);



    ?>
```